# How to make children DIV inherit parent DIV height

Tags: jquery-selectors

I saw many similar questions asked before, but I couldn't one that matched what I'm looking for.

I would like the height of the red boxes to stretch 100%, essentially inheriting the parent row's height.

I tried fiddling with jquery commands for awhile, but I haven't had much luck.  Below is the code.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js">
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $("div.grid_leftcol").css("height", $(this).parent().innerHeight());
        //This syntax probably doesn't make any sense, but it might give you a sense of what I'm trying to do

        $("div.grid_leftcol").css("height", $("div.grid_leftcol").parent().innerHeight());
        //This one kind of works, but the height of the red boxes are all the same.
    });
  </script>
  <style>
  .grid_row {
    border-bottom:1px solid #aaa
  }
  .grid_rightcol_rxrow div { display:inline-block}
  .grid_rightcol_rxrow div.grid_commentbox { display:block }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height:485px">
        <div class="grid_row" style="background-color:#dde2e7" id="testrow">
          <div class="grid_leftcol" id="testcol" style="display:inline-block; width:225px; background-color:red; vertical-align:top">
            <div>Variable height content</div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid_rightcol" style="display:inline-block;">
            <div class="grid_rightcol_rxrow">
                <div style="width:22px">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="baba" value="checkbox">
                </div>
                <div style="width:110px">Row 1a</div>
                <div style="width:110px">(OC)</div>
                <div>John</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_rightcol_rxrow">
                <div style="width:22px">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="baba" value="checkbox">
                </div>
                <div style="width:110px">Row 1b</div>
                <div style="width:110px">(OC)</div>
                <div>Mary</div>
                <div class="grid_commentbox" style="padding:3px 3px 3px 25px">This is where comment goes</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_rightcol_rxrow">
                <div style="width:22px">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="baba" value="checkbox">
                </div>
                <div style="width:110px">Row 1c</div>
                <div style="width:110px">(OC)</div>
                <div>Larry</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_row" style="background-color:#dde2e7">
          <div class="grid_leftcol" style="display:inline-block; width:225px; background-color:red; vertical-align:top">
            <div>Variable height content<br>
            Variable height content<br>
            Variable height content</div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid_rightcol" style="display:inline-block;">
            <div class="grid_rightcol_rxrow">
                <div style="width:22px">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="baba" value="checkbox">
                </div>
                <div style="width:110px">Row 2a</div>
                <div style="width:110px">(OC)</div>
                <div>Jen</div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid_row" style="background-color:#dde2e7">
          <div class="grid_leftcol" style="display:inline-block; width:225px; background-color:red; vertical-align:top">
            <div>Variable height content</div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid_rightcol" style="display:inline-block;">
            <div class="grid_rightcol_rxrow">
                <div style="width:22px">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="baba" value="checkbox">
                </div>
                <div style="width:110px">Row 3a</div>
                <div style="width:110px">(OC)</div>
                <div>Geroge</div>
            </div>
<div class="grid_rightcol_rxrow">
                <div style="width:22px">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="baba" value="checkbox">
                </div>
                <div style="width:110px">Row 3b</div>
                <div style="width:110px">(OC)</div>
                <div>Robert</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a table (and even though I haven't coded one in ages), this looks like it would be a perfect candidate.  I refactored your code http://jsfiddle.net/brianflanagan/4NXzg/ as an example.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this.  I agree 100% that this is easier with table. And this was actually originally coded using a table a few years ago.  But I wanted to see what kind of problems I would run into using non-table approach.